# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

Tags: php, windows, tiff, imagick, pecl

I am trying to create JPEG image from TIFF binary data. I call a SOAP service and get a TIFF binary array as follows:

```
$val = array(
                "arg0" => XXX,
                "arg1" => XXX,
        );

        $headerbody  = array(
                'Username'=>XXX,
                'Password'=>XXX,
        );
$wsdl =  'wsdl services url';   
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
            $soap_var_header = new SoapVar($headerbody, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
            $header = new SoapHeader("http://webservices.averittexpress.com/authn",'authnHeader', $soap_var_header);
            $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
            $value = $client->getDocument($val);

        try {           
        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->readImageBlob($value->return);
        $im->setFormat('JPEG');
        file_put_contents('Test.jpeg', $im->getImageBlob());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
```

The problem is that the code fails with error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

I have enabled `php_imagick.dll` in php.ini:

```
; Imagick Extension
[Imagick]
extension = "php_imagick.dll"
```

`php_imagick` library is displayed as PHP extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A test script like `<?php var_dump(extension_loaded('imagick'), new Imagick());` would be enough for this question

Comment: Still same error Class Imagic is not found

Comment: could it be a namespace problem? try `new \Imagick()`

Comment: @jeff Sir same issue

Comment: Have you restarted the web server after enabling Imagick?

Comment: Yes web server and system both restart but same issue

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, try to remove `[Imagick]` from php.ini, or move the `extension` line to the global section (`[PHP]`, preferably somewhere after `extension_dir`), then restart the Web server and test again

Comment: Do you see Imagick in `phpinfo();`? Checked the servers error log, in case it can't find the extension?

Comment: i am not able to see imagic in phpinfo();

Comment: Then the extension isn't loaded correctly. Checked the server log? Tried @RuslanOsmanov suggestion? Also, check that the dll-file/extension exists in the same folder as the other dll-files/extensions.

Comment: pls give me extension_dir syntex for me. i try extension_dir = "php_imagick.dll". but soapcall error

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, put `extension = "php_imagick.dll"` into the _global section_, i.e. `[PHP]`. You will probably find a number of commented-out lines for different extensions: `; extension = ...`. If you find them, put your line right after the last such line.

Comment: Still same issue class is not found

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, please share your php.ini and/or the output of `print_r(ini_get_all());` via some online service such as Github's Gists,

Comment: I am using wamp64 bit and php 5.6.25 version. pls give me which imagick dll version download.

Comment: Thanks to all for help me i got solution. i put one another file with "php_imagick.dll" with "php_imagick.pdb" on ext folder and got solution